# text box data in form - not being passed on AJAX submission

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

The textbox (id: handle) is not having its data passed via post on AJAX submission.

Form:

```
  <form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="form1">
 <LABEL for:="handle">Twitter Handle </LABEL>
 <INPUT type="text" id="handle" value="@">
 <input name="hidden_data" id='hidden_data' type="hidden"/>
 </form>
```

I have a button:

```
     <input type="button" id="sharebutton" onclick="uploadEx()" value="Share" />
```

This is my function (uploadEx):

```
      function uploadEx() {
                    var handle = document.getElementById('handle');

            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            document.getElementById('hidden_data').value = dataURL;

            var fd = new FormData(document.forms["form1"]);

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'upload_data.php', true);

            xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
                if (e.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                    console.log(percentComplete + '% uploaded');

                    alert('Selfie Succesfully uploaded');
                }
            };

            xhr.onload = function() {

            };
            xhr.send(fd);
        };
```

My picture (Canvas) gets passed back to upload_data.php and is processed.

The textbox, handle, doesn't have anything passed as POST.

I don't know where the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text input doesn't have a `name` attribute, add it and it should work:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="form1">
<LABEL for:="handle">Twitter Handle </LABEL>
<INPUT type="text" id="handle" name="mytext" value="@">
<input name="hidden_data" id='hidden_data' type="hidden"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You are right. I should have added the name. Confused name attribute with id.